# Jquery append/prepend svg and find child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

How can I append/prepend an element to body, such as svg inline code, then find a child within the appended svg with jquery?

I tried:

```
$('body').prepend(varWithSvgCode).find('path')
```

But that seems to select all paths of all svg elements within body I assume.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `prepend()` will return the element that was *appended to*, ie. the `body`, not the content which was appended.

To fix this you can invert your logic to build a jQuery object from the content before prepending it, then perform your `find()`:

```
var path = $(varWithSvgCode).prependTo('body').find('path');
```